# How to copy only files which have repetitive string in names to any folder using nested loop?

Tags: python, string, operating-system, filenames, shutil

I need to copy filed which contain specific any string in their name to any folder.  I use working code using os and shutil modules, which copies all text files to destination folder.

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\\FOLDER\\'
dest = r'C:\\ANY_FOLDER\\'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        if 'posted' in filename:
            shutil.copy2(filename, dest)
```

How to amend the code to copy only files which contain string 'posted' in names? Correct code is present after insertion of code in line above the last one.

Comment: use if to check, `if 'posted' in filename:shutil.copy2(filename, dest)`

Answer (score 1):

To copy and maintaining the directory structure.

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'srcdir'
dest = r'destdir'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)

        if 'posted' in filename:
            full_dest_path = os.path.join(dest, filename.lstrip(src).lstrip('/'))

            dirname = os.path.dirname(full_dest_path)
            if not os.path.exists(dirname):
                os.makedirs(dirname)

            shutil.copy2(filename, full_dest_path)
```

To copy and not maintain the directory structure, as in just copy the file to the dest dir.

```
import os
import shutil

src = r'srcdir'
dest = r'destdir'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)

        if 'posted' in filename:
            shutil.copy2(filename, os.path.join(dest, name))
```

Comment: Mindaugas, did this help?